# using a struct pointer to display a 1-D array

Tags: c++, c

> I am using a pointer to a struct array inorder to display the content
>   of that array. The code compiles without errors but the output is
>   incorrect.
>
> i have tried using the following formats `*(ptr).re`,`*(ptr)[j]`.re or
>   just `(*ptr)`.re to see if any of them displays of inputed values

```
struct structure    //creating struct called structure to contain the real 
                         and imaginary parts of a complex vector 
{
    float Re;       //Data type float for Real part called Re
    float Im;       //Data type float for Imaginary part called Im
};



/*simple function for inputing user difined Re and Im values and storing them using a pointer to the sturct variable in the main function*/

void extract_Re_and_Im(structure *complex) 
{

printf("please enter the real number\n");   //this stores the real part
    scanf("%i",&(*complex).Re);

printf("please enter the Imaginary number\n");//this stores the Imaginary part
    scanf("%i",&(*complex).Im);
}

/*function with a return of pointer of data type sturcture.the function should store multiple complex vectors*/

structure *extract_array_of_Re_and_Im(structure*complex,int size_of_array,int i) 

{ 
structure complex_1[size_of_array];
i++; //this is a static variable in main
extract_Re_and_Im(complex); //this function allows user to input the complex vector and stores it into a varible in the function main by using a pointer
    complex_1[i].Re=(*complex).Re;  
    complex_1[i].Im=(*complex).Im;

    return complex_1;
}

int main()
{
const int SIZE=9;//creating SIZE this specifies how many complex vectors the program holds

for(i;i<SIZE;i++)//a loop used to allow user to enter all the complex vectors 
{
extract_array_of_Re_and_Im(&complex_number,SIZE,i); //a function that creates a 1-D matrix of data type structure for storing user entered complex vectors 
}

Ptr_for_complex=extract_array_of_Re_and_Im(&complex_number,SIZE,i); 
//this stores the memory address thats returned by the function, the addr is for the 1-D matrix of data type structure

    printf("everything is ok\n");       //just a failure checker

for(int j=0;j<SIZE;j++) //this is a loop to display the user inputed data in the correct format N + J M
{
printf("your Re and Im numbers are %.2f and J%.2f\n",Ptr_for_complex[j].Re,Ptr_for_complex[j].Im); 

//this should display the contents of the structure array
    }
}
```

> i expected: 10 + J10 9 + J9 . . . 1 + J 1 but got nothing and a non 0
>   error for the return 0 in main

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

This code is wrong

```
structure *extract_array_of_Re_and_Im(structure*complex,int size_of_array,int i) 
{ 
    structure complex_1[size_of_array];
    i++; //this is a static variable in main
    extract_Re_and_Im(complex); //this function allows user to input the complex vector and stores it into a varible in the function main by using a pointer
    complex_1[i].Re=(*complex).Re;  
    complex_1[i].Im=(*complex).Im;
    return complex_1;
}
```

It's wrong in two different ways. Firstly it's not legal C++ because in C++ array sizes must be *compile time constants*. In your code `size_of_array` is a variable.

Secondly and more seriously the function returns a pointer to the array `complex_1` but **the array no longer exists after the function has exited**. So in this code

```
Ptr_for_complex=extract_array_of_Re_and_Im(&complex_number,SIZE,i);
```

`Ptr_for_complex` is pointing at an array which no longer exists.

Really the whole code is very confused, and far too complicated. What you are trying to do doesn't require all this complexity.

Here's one way to do it properly

```
void extract_Re_and_Im(structure *complex) 
{
    printf("please enter the real number\n");   //this stores the real part
    scanf("%i", &complex->Re);
    printf("please enter the Imaginary number\n");//this stores the Imaginary part
    scanf("%i", &complex->Im);
}

int main()
{
    const int SIZE=9;
    structure complex_array[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        extract_Re_and_Im(&complex_array[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
        printf("your Re and Im numbers are %.2f and J%.2f\n", complex_array[j].Re, complex_array[j].Im); 
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation, is their any way to have a variable array?, secondly When you say the Ptr_for_complex is pointing to nothing. do you mean that the data in ram is no longer their? i am also trying to understand stakes so does that mean the data has been poped off? again thank you very much for your time.

Comment: The simplest way to have a variable array is to use a `std::vector`. E.g. `#include <vector> ... std:vector<structure> complex_array(size);`. The other way is to use dynamic allocation `structure* complex_array = new structure[size];` but that's more complicated, so I'd recommend that you learn about vectors.

Comment: Yes, more or less. The precise way to say it is that if you try to access data which no longer exists using a pointer then the behaviour of your program is undefined.

Comment: I think you mean *stack* not *stake*. All that popped off means is that the data has been removed from the top of the stack.